# How can I show options after LongClick?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I need to program something like the image:

[image: example]

When I long click a item in a ListView two options appear in the toolbar, to delete the item or cancel the action.

I want to make exactly like that, I do not want a context menu (which I know how to do).

Is it possible to do this with simple code? If no, can I accomplish that manipulating the toolbar? How can I do that?

PS: I can only use native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use contextual Action Mode Over Toolbar.For Using Action Mode we need to extend our class with ActionMode.Callback. Its a Callback interface for action modes. Supplied to startSupportActionMode(Callback) (Callback)}, a Callback configures and handles events raised by a user’s interaction with an action mode.You need to override following method.

```
    onCreateActionMode(ActionMode, Menu) once on initial creation.
    onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode, Menu) after creation and any time the ActionMode is 
    invalidated.
    onActionItemClicked(ActionMode, MenuItem) any time a contextual action button is 
    clicked.
    onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode) when the action mode is closed.
```

Comment: It works, but it shows another bar above the toolbar. It is supposed to be this way?

Comment: Just added `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` to the style, thanks